# C++: Is it better to store a console output in a macro?

Tags: c++, macros, cout

I just started to get into some basics of C++, but there were two things I've realized:

1. The difference between Macros and Functions is that macros are preprocessed while Functions are compiled afterwards
2. In every code I've read (also some with defined macros), no one ever defined a macro for a console output

Now my question is, should you even do such a thing?

Without Macro:

```
//...
cout << "This is a test";
cout << "This is another test";
cout << "This is a third test" << " with two strings in one";
//..
```

With Macro:

```
#define OUTP(x) (cout << x)

//...
OUTP("This is a test");
OUTP("This is another test");
OUTP("This is a third test" + " with two strings in one");
//...
```

First, I can't see a big difference, except I don't get so confused with the macro, cause normally "<<" is bitshifting, but here it's used for insertion, while "OUTP("Test")" looks better for me, as it works like a normal method.

But as I've never seen someone using that, is there a reason behind that?

Comment: I would suggest using a common convention of writing macros in all caps, so OUTP

Comment: And how would we deal with `cout << "Total number of apples:" << 42;`? We still need `<<`.

Comment: `OUTP("This is a third test" + " with two strings in one");` will not compile.

Comment: Re: "normally `<<` is bitshifting" -- back in the olden days that was true. These days it's stream insertion (through operator overloading), and many beginners don't even know that it's also bitshifting.

Comment: The **big** difference is that `cout << "This is a test";` is C++ code while `OUTP("This is a test");` is something you made up. I have been there and I have done that, but once you work on any serious project you will notice that it is easier to write C++ code instead of trying to make up something "better"

Comment: You mean the performance, or the general readability?

Comment: In modern `c++` you should avoid macros as much as possible. Although I do see them used in logging libraries that don't log in release mode.

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn it's basically about not reinventing square wheels when round wheels work well

Comment: yes, there are still 1 or 2 cases where macros are useful, for logging you sometimes need `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` or `__FUNCTION__` but that is really the only cases I would not reject in a code review

Comment: @idclev463035818: That case is resolved in C++20 with [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I cannot believe it. This is no hoax is it? macros: goodbye :)

Comment: How about `template <typename T> void OUTP(const T& x) { std::cout << x; }` instead of `#define OUTP(x) (cout << x)`?

Comment: what about `#define newl (cout << "\n")`. That saves time when I need a new line

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn Saving time is not a good reason. Your goal should be correctness, readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: how about `#define newl (cout << "\n")` ? That will waste time of others reading the code because they will have to search your code for the definition of `newl` just to find that all it does is add a new line to `cout`. Also consider what you would to if you want to write a newline to a file? Would you write a second macro? Would you provide two parameters for the macro? This design already has been worked out and the outcome is: write `std::cout << '\n';` when you want to add a new line to `cout`

Comment: Macros are more than functions:  `#define CAPACITY 4`.  Macros do not support type checking (safety), functions support type checking.  Prefer functions and constant identifiers to macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Better" is a really vague term, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Every implementation decision has its pros and cons, so it is really up to the single project.

From what I can see, the pros of **abstracting** the output behind a macro could be:

- Easier way to swap out output method in favor of more manageable logging structures in case the need comes
- less typing
- more uniformity if the macro takes charge in adding some common formatting options

Cons could be:

- you lose flexibility, as inevitably the macro will not allow some operations that directly using cout would have allowed
- you add a layer of indirection and get away from a common practice of the language. People with experience in the language will pick up cout faster, otherwise they will have to look for the content of the macro and get used to it.

There are surely other reason for or against such a choice, but in the end I think there is no right choice.

P.S.

> so confused with the macro, cause normally "<<" is bitshifting, but here it's used for insertion,

While surely a good reason, I suggest you look at it the other side. "bitshifting" operator for output is a pattern common in C++, so you should start being a little more flexible in how you interpret the operator due to [operator overloading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a function (template) instead of macros?

Comment: @walnut the question specifically asks for macros, so I addressed that. template functions will still give you mostly the same pros and cons, at least the ones I wrote in the answer.

Comment: The question was "Now my question is, should you even do such a thing?". The reason this is shouldn't be done is because using functions is a better alternative in almost every case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "almost" :)

Comment: @bracco23 "Almost" is hedging for cases like when you need `__FILE__` or something like that. But answers shouldn't target the edge cases unless they are the subject of the question.

Comment: I guess my problem with the answer is that it presents Pros as advantages relative to do doing nothing instead. It doesn't account for alternative solutions, which are the main reason why using macros for this is a bad idea. The Pros listed here are not advantages for macros relative to using template functions.

Comment: I tried to focus more on abstracting vs using common patterns because I think most of the doubts behind the question is there. As I said before, there is no difference between the cons I have listed for macros and the ones I would have listed for functions. Are macros technically worse than function? yes. Are they the preferred solution when talking about abstracting output functionalities? It depends.

Answer (score 1):

I am using macros for outputs. It has certain advantages over conventional output, namely:

1. You can change lately all outputs at one place - at macro definition. For example, if you want to prefix all outputs with a timestamp, with macro employment you need to change only your macro once.
2. You can introduce output level, like `DEBUG` or `INFO` or `ERROR.` Depending on the given output level (e.g. `ERROR`), your matching outputs will be compiled (e.g. `ERROR` and `FATAL_ERROR`) and performed, all other irrelevant outputs (e.g. `DEBUG`) will be even not compiled and not included into the binary code. Moreover, many IDEs will even grey out irrelevant code lines.
3. You can also introduce variable number of input arguments, code line number, date and time of compilation and so in macros. And even employ mutex for multi-threading output, since `cout << "first" << "second";` is not thread-safe (another thread can output something between your `"first"` and `"second"` strings).
4. etc. There are plenty articles in Internet about this topic.

Comment: All of these can be done much cleaner with functions rather than macros.

Comment: @walnut 1) It depends on "cleaner" definition. 2) Then all outputs with functions (even not relevant to the given output level) will be compiled and included into binary.

Comment: If you make the functions templates, only the used cases will be compiled.

Comment: @walnut all function calls will be compiled and included. Even not desired for a given output level. Or is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: You make the function a template and let each log level have a unique type, then you make the target log level a compile-time constant and check simply let the body of the function be empty if the level does not match (either with `if constexpr` or with partial specialization) It doesn't really matter anyway though, because the compiler will optimize the call away anyway if the target log level is a compile-time constant.

Comment: @AndreyBelkin Very small functions such as one that simply wraps a stream operation will probably be inlined. Here is [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/BkFt_n) where the function template and macro are completely equivalent in terms of assembly generated. Nothing in this answer supports the use of macros that you can't also easily do with functions.

Comment: @walnut thank you. It can be a good solution. Possible drawbacks are: more code, less portability to C (if ever needed).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you. Maybe this case is a matter of habits and taste.